# Use and modify existing Opsworks stack in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, opsworks

I want to create a stack in AWS CloudFormation that uses OpsWorks resources to create a new environment for my application. The thing is that my app needs the OpsWorks stack's id predefined, so I created it manually because I can't declare the id in CloudFormation's template. Is there a way to use this stack in CloudFormation and modify it (e.g. update Custom JSON)?

Thank you

Comment: The stack ID should be in the Chef stack attributes, is there a reason you can't obtain the stack ID from your instance that way? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-json-opsworks-stack.html#attributes-json-opsworks-stack-id